# collapseEmptyDivs on DFP gets ignored?

Tags: google-dfp

I see an empty ad pretty often & I'd like to collapse the space. I know this could be done easily by including *googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs()* 
However, this doesn't work as expected, the space is there, just empty. When I inspect element, this is what I got:

```
border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom; visibility: hidden; display: none;
```

When I do google_console sometimes I also saw a warning "collapseEmptyDivs gets ignored". Weirdest part is, when I click on google_console "open creative in new window" - I see the ad. What could go wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try passing `true` to `googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(true)` which makes the ad hidden until it matches an ad.